# Service Account in K8s have access to other namespaces that are not part of its role

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, k8s-serviceaccount, kubernetes-rbac

I want to create a service account that can access to specific namespaces, so far some rules are working the issue comes when I export the KUBECONFIG, this service account can do anything in other pods that are in other NS that this account should not have access to.

Here is the code.

```bash
# Create a service account for the user
kubectl create serviceaccount ${USERNAME} --namespace=${NAMESPACE_SA}

# Create the RBAC role
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: ${ROLE_NAME}
  namespace: ${NAMESPACE}
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["create", "get", "update", "list"]
EOF

# Bind the user to the role
kubectl create rolebinding ${USERNAME}-rolebinding --role=${ROLE_NAME} --serviceaccount=${NAMESPACE_SA}:${USERNAME} --namespace=${NAMESPACE}

# Create token for the SA (k8s 1.24+)
kubectl create token ${USERNAME} --namespace=${NAMESPACE_SA}
```

Accessing to the K8s cluster

```bash
export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/my-sa-kubeconfig && kubectl config use-context kubernetes-admin@kubernetes-user-sa && kubectl get pods -A

# User SA should have access only to the default NS, but this SA can interact as well with all pods in the redis NS

default                temporalio-matching-b5576d445-4nwn6                      1/1     Running            1          132d
default                temporalio-web-5c96bcb4d6-c5gff                          1/1     Running            1          132d
default                temporalio-worker-767768d4f6-fqdhw                       1/1     Running            1          132d
redis-cluster          redis-primary-67dd67f4b6-b66gl                           1/1     Running            1          343d
redis-cluster          redis-replica-7bd77d7485-5n8js                           1/1     Running            1          343d
redis-cluster          redis-replica-7bd77d7485-zvb4h                           1/1     Running            1          343d
```

Any hints where this is failing?
Note, after evaluating the Bash variables files are correct, and no erros are shown.

- I have already tried creating a ClusterRole and bind it to a role for an specific NS , and no luck
- I have tried to limit verbs to only list on the pods resource and I can still do kubectl exec in the NS that the role does not have access